# Concat in Arrayformula using row numbers

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

## UPDATE - Modified answer

With help from @player0, found solution that handled line seperators too:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY( IF(D1:D="[task]", "♦"&D1:D, "♣♀"&D1:D),,999^99), "♦", )), "♀")),,999^99)),"\s*♣\s*",char(10)))`

This moves each [task] section into its own cell, retaining all other formatting, and stops the extra whitespace that gets added around each cells content that are joined/concat together.

---

## Original Post

Can't seem to find anywhere else this is done, so happy for any links in comments too :)

I have a column of text, the contents of over a hundred files with `[task]` at top of each.

**More than 50,000 characters**, so they pasted into a newline each cell ('paste as values').

I can easily tell the row numbers to work with and have a draggable working formula, just can't get it properly **ARRAYFORMULA capable**, since the input might change by easily a thousand rows so needs to handle that gracefully.

*Formulas only please, no code*

**Example Spreadsheet**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yaETa3Pvq47DpcAyojSlf6p5N1Tt_hpvoqp7WEtC6pI/edit?usp=sharing

**Example Input (50,000+ characters)**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sMl0ZQfbXZUjpB0fic2VkX5Ze5H_IEGL/view?usp=sharing

*Note - if the input file is removed when I clean my drive up, just copy-paste the sample below till 50,000+ characters, or see linked spreadsheet*

**Input**

```
[task]
SpriteNE = floor_metal_01.dds
SpriteSE = floor_metal_01.dds
SpriteSW = floor_metal_01.dds
SpriteNW = floor_metal_01.dds
guilevel = 1
guiindex = 10
type = COMPONENT
locked = 0
name = category_advanced_manufacturing
parent

[task]
SpriteNE = floor_metal_01.dds
SpriteSE = floor_metal_01.dds
SpriteSW = floor_metal_01.dds
SpriteNW = floor_metal_01.dds
guilevel = 1
guiindex = 9
type = COMPONENT
locked = 0
name = category_facilities
parent

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = 1
parent
guiindex = 0.5
name = task_conveyor
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_converge3_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_converge3_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_converge3_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_converge3_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0,
inputdirectionoffsets = 1,2,3
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_converge3
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_converge3_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_crossover_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_crossover_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_crossover_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_crossover_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0,3
inputdirectionoffsets = 1,2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_crossover
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_crossover_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_left_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_left_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_left_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_left_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 3
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_left
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_left_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_right_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_right_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_right_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_right_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 1
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_right
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_right_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_split3_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_split3_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_split3_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_split3_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0,1,3
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_split3
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_split3_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_t_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_t_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_t_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_t_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 3,1
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_t
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_t_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_t_join_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_t_join_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_t_join_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_t_join_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0
inputdirectionoffsets = 1,3
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_t_join
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_t_join_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_t_join_left_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_t_join_left_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_t_join_left_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_t_join_left_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0
inputdirectionoffsets = 2,3
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_t_join_left
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_t_join_left_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_t_join_right_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_t_join_right_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_t_join_right_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_t_join_right_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0
inputdirectionoffsets = 1,2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_t_join_right
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_t_join_right_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_t_left_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_t_left_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_t_left_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_t_left_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0,3
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_t_left
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_t_left_SE.dds

[task]
tilelable
SpriteNE = conveyor_t_right_NE.dds
SpriteSE = conveyor_t_right_SE.dds
SpriteSW = conveyor_t_right_SW.dds
SpriteNW = conveyor_t_right_NW.dds
exitdirectionoffsets = 0,1
inputdirectionoffsets = 2
guilevel = -1
parent
guiindex = 1
name = task_conveyor_t_right
is_conveyor = 1

[components]

[resources]

[subtasksrequired]

[subtasksapplied]

[tile]
texture = conveyor_t_right_SE.dds
```

**Desired Output**

Each [task].* is a new file, so seperate by those into one cell each in a single column, with newlines (`\n`) as internal separators.

In other words, everything after [task] till the next [task] (or end of column, if no more [task]) combined into one cell each.

Just has to be arrayformula able and avoid the char limit for functions like concat of 50,000 characters.

**Current Output**

*Getting row numbers*

`$D$1:D` is the input column

`$G$1` is dropdown with `"[task]"` selected

```
$M$1 =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({$D1:$D, row($D1:$D)},"select * where Col1 = '"&$G$1&"'"))
```

```
$O$1 =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({$M1:$M,{$M2:$M;0}},"select *"))
```

Then some of my attempts to use these numbers

*Works, has to be dragged through, and **doesn't have any separators**.*

`=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("$D"&$O1:$O&":$D"&$P1:$P-1)))`

*Doesn't work, I kept adding more arrayformula but still just first result*

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($P1:P<>"",CONCATENATE(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("$D"&ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("$O"&IF($P1:$P<>"",row($P1:$P),"")&":$O"))&":$D"&ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("$P"&IF($P1:$P<>"",row($P1:$P),"")&":$P"))-1))),""))`

*Just the string used in previous INDIRECT*

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($O1:O<>"","$D"&ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("$O"&IF($P1:$P<>"",row($P1:$P),"")&":$O"))&":$D"&ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("$P"&IF($P1:$P<>"",row($P1:$P),"")&":$P"))-1,""))`

*Doesn't work, has separators but still only looping the first result.*

`$U1:U` is the string list for indirects (see above)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF($U1:U<>"",TEXTJOIN(";",FALSE,INDIRECT($U1:U)),""))`

There are some other formulas in the example sheet, I mostly removed the duds as I kept going though.

I found lots of interesting resources out there but nothing that seemed to target using row numbers, or even just SPLIT + JOIN type approach that allowed `ARRAYFORMULA` (**AND avoided the 50,000 character limit** issue with single CONCAT or similar calls).

Comment: *EDIT* - added textjoin formula to description and example spreadsheet, has seperators but still looping first result

Comment: it's more easy if you permit it to use macro function

Comment: @user11982798 - im not familiar with those, ive done a bit with google scripts and formulas, trying to make this as plug and play as possible, no script permissions or libraries or anything. Your welcome to provide a macro answer if you have one, i might not accept it if isnt matching end use case but ill upvote if looks good anyway

Comment: I have made the macro as in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF(A2:A="[task]", "♦"&A2:A, "♀"&A2:A),,999^99), "♦", )), "♀"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Looks good, another project getting in way atm so not tested yet, however would be great to know if can be modified to concat those columns virtually (without needing to let them print then concat via seperate formula) so output is just single column like OP requested?

 that way no need for seperate sheet or like to allow for that variable column count.

Comment: thanks for the link, i know that. What im currently saying is that I very quickly tested it now and while it does what you say, my feedback is that doesnt answer OP, so cant accept it yet. If you can adjust it so outputs to single column, then id love to accept and upvote :)

Comment: Looked again and realised maybe not as clear as i could be in OP that was desired output, so upvoted but please adjust so i can accept as answer :)

Comment: Sorry if any confusion, my example sheet had output examples i detailed in OP too (just not proper arrayformula capable), but def could have improved that one paragraph to be clearer :)

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 IF(A2:A="[task]", "♦"&A2:A, "♀"&A2:A),,999^99), "♦", )), "♀")),,999^99)))`

Comment: Thanks for that, i modified it to keep newlines, i have a space before each seperated line in the cells now though, unsure why. ```=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY( IF(D1:D="[task]", "♦"&D1:D, "♣♀"&D1:D),,999^99), "♦", )), "♀")),,999^99)),"♣",char(10)))```

Comment: Okay, so they were the spaces added when cells where combined, still cant see how to avoid them appearing, so have a crude workaround: ```=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY( IF(D1:D="[task]", "♦"&D1:D, "♣♀"&D1:D),,999^99), "♦", )), "♀")),,999^99)),"♣ ",char(10)))``` Will update my OP with this answer, though prob best you also update this here :)

Comment: Issues from that extra whitespace thats actually on both sides of each line, so updated it, see updated OP

Answer (score 1):

This is sample as I said before in comment, you just call function in cell "=GroupMacro" unfortunately, this can't be auto refresh:

```
var rtrn=[];
var rslt=[];
var rslt2='';

function GroupMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var bomo=spreadsheet.getRange('D1:D' + spreadsheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  for (a=0; a<bomo.length; a++)
  {
    if(bomo[a]=='test') //this is separator, this can be applied as parameter in function
    {
      if(a>0)
      {
         rslt2=rslt.join();
         rtrn.push(rslt2);
         rslt=[];
      }
      rslt.push(bomo[a]);
    }
    else
    {
      rslt.push(bomo[a]);
    }
  }
  rslt2=rslt.join();
  rtrn.push(rslt2);
  return rtrn;
};
```

Comment: ill check this out when i get back to this project, likely cant accept as answer but if works great ill def upvote so others notice it when searching SO themselves :)

Comment: Ok, this script actually works pretty great. I didnt bother creating as macro, just added to scripts ran it as custom formula, so likely will refresh on page refresh, though dont quote on that. As i said though, cant accept as answer since doesnt answer OP, def worth upvote though as may help others, especially as pretty simple google will show how to change those variables (range and seperator) into either fomula params or input prompts. Thanks for great example